# error executing s3 putObject api using aws sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2-advanced-app

I am using php AWS SDK, to upload objects to s3, I set the bucket policy as below:

```
            {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "AddPerm",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": "*",
                        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Sid": "Stmt1488493308547",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "IAMuserARN"
                        },
                        "Action": "s3:*",
                        "Resource": [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

and set IAM user policy to have full access of s3. 
but when I run the code to putObject I get an exception of:

> Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/uploads/media/media_36_file.png"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/uploads/media/media_36_file.png` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: AccessDeniedAccess DeniedF78430 (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - AccessDeniedAccess DeniedF784301719C49C953fPX0U28ONnHQuUvJKJGQ3VBUfELBqmxyWL2gI7G7RS6G3D4qgA2K74Kgh1kOmrfMfEEJinL8Cw=

Comment: Is the AWS client definitely picking your credentials up properly?

Comment: I checked the key and the secret twice and still having the same error @gandaliter

Comment: @gandaliter you are right, I was setting the key and secret separately while I should provide them under "credentials" key